# how to set View height in tablelayout in android?

Tags: android

I have a problem i want to set View in table layout and manage the height but i am not able to set the height. it is taking bydefault height.

Note:- view is in red color

please give me any idea for this.

/* this is my code */

tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

```
    View lineview = new View(this); 
  lineview.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

    //lineview.setPadding(0, 1, 0, 0);

    //lineview.setMinimumHeight(1);

    lineview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
    tableLayout.addView(lineview);

    final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lpt =(MarginLayoutParams)lineview.getLayoutParams();
    lpt.setMargins(lpt.leftMargin,lpt.topMargin,lpt.rightMargin,lpt.bottomMargin=2);
```

/* and this is my layout */

[image]

"Thanks"

Comment: post your xml, you want to set the red view height? Is all the content a table or just the red view?

Comment: it is not through xml

Comment: why are you using TableLayout for one view?

Comment: it is not only one view

Comment: It is not very clear what you want
TableLayout has TableRows and they have height, see: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_TableLayout_and_TableRow_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width and height of the view in this line...

**`lineview.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));`**

You are giving the height and width of the table to the view so that your view(in red color) has the same height as the tablelayout

change that line with your custom height and width

**`lineview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));`**